# Field jwtTokenProvider in security.JwtAuthenticationFilter required a bean of type 'security.JwtTokenProvider' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to Springboot and i hope you can help me.
I'm doing a back application in SpringBoot for a react native app and i'm stuck.
I want to secure my app with a jwt  but
when i try to launch my application i have this message andi don't understand why i got this.

> ```
> ***************************
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
> ***************************
>
> Description:
>
> Field jwtTokenProvider in asrouen.projet2.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter required a bean of
> type 'asrouen.projet2.security.JwtTokenProvider' that could not be
> found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>         - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'asrouen.projet2.security.JwtTokenProvider' in your configuration.
> ```

JwtTokenProvider Class

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenProvider.class);

    @Value(value = "${app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value(value = "${app.jwtExpirationInMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationInMs;

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();

        Date now = new Date();
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + jwtExpirationInMs);

        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(Long.toString(userPrincipal.getId())).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expiryDate).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret).compact();
    }

    public Long getUserIdFromJWT(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();

        return Long.valueOf(claims.getSubject());
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Invalid JWT signature");
        } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Invalid JWT token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Expired JWT token");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Unsupported JWT token");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("JWT claims string is empty");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and JwtAuthenticationFilter Class

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                Long userId = jwtTokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope to read from you soon

Comment: I was looking for how the secret key was defined and found this over github. Sharing here if anyone is coming here looking for this example. Here is the complete implementation : https://github.com/Arab04/JWTTokenProviderWithAuthentication/tree/master/polling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In which package is your application class? (annotated with @SpringBootApplication)?

Spring boot will normally only search for @Component in the same package or any of its sub-packages.

Comment: i had this in my application class ( @ComponentScan("asrouen.projet2.entity") now it's fine ty !